# JavaScriptSerializer has registerconverters, how to call base deserialize method in RegisterConverts Class

Tags: c#, serialization, javascriptserializer

I have a JavaScriptSerializer with RegisterConverters Class to Serialize DataTime.  In the same class I have `Deserialize` method which throws `NotImplementedException`.  `RegisterConverters` Class is working fine when Serializing a object.

When using the same `JavaScriptSerializer` object to DeSerialize Json Object back to required Class object it is throwing `NotImplementedException`.

Here I don't want to use `Deserilize` method of `RegisterConverters` Class.  How can I achive that?  It just work as a new `JavaScriptSerializer` object which has no `RegisterConverters` when deserializing.

```
public class DefaultNullPropertiesConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jsonExample = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //check if decorated with ScriptIgnore attribute
            bool ignoreProp = prop.IsDefined(typeof(ScriptIgnoreAttribute), true);

            var value = prop.GetValue(obj, BindingFlags.Public, null, null, null);
            if (value != null && !ignoreProp)
            {
                if (value.GetType().FullName == "System.DateTime" && Convert.ToDateTime(value) == DateTime.MinValue)
                    continue;
                else if (value.GetType().FullName == "System.DateTime")
                    jsonExample.Add(prop.Name, Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                else
                    jsonExample.Add(prop.Name, value);
            }
        }

        return jsonExample;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return GetType().Assembly.GetTypes(); }
    }

}
```

Now when I call Deserialize method:

```
var restGeoCodeResponse rgcr = jss.Deserialize<restGeoCodeResponse>(result);
```

this should not call Deserialize method of DefaultNullPropertiesConverter class. Just deserialize as it doesnot have any RegisterConverts.

Answer (score 0):

So the first question I would ask is what are you passing to the RegisterConverters method?  Did you write your own JavascriptConverter to handle DateTime Serialization and Deserialization.  If so then the JavascriptConverter class that you wrote probably has a throws NotImplementedException in the Deserialize method.

If you are using a 3rd party JavascriptConverter I would look at their source code or if you do not have their source code decompile the source using a tool like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) from JetBrains or [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) from Telerik

Comment: Yes you are right Michael.  I wrote my own JavaScriptConverter Class and it has throw NotImplementedException.  Here my question is I don't want compiler to call this DeSerialize method.

Comment: Please how to call base Deserialize method in DefaultNullPropertiesConverter Class instead of throw NotImplementedException  exception